# How do I unescape a string?

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

using ajax get method to pass a variable.  where i use to escape the string with escape() function.

In php, I receive the value and insert into a database.

**How do I unescape the string?**

For example, for:

```
balaji's
```

I get

```
balaji%27s.
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this function instead of urldecode()

```
function utf8_urldecode($str) {
        return html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i", "&#x\\1;", urldecode($str)), null, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: For me, it was useful to know that `html_entity_decode($str, null, 'UTF-8')` decodes characters escaped like "&#227". I am just writing it here so it is easier for others to see it if they have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
htmlspecialchars(urldecode($str));
```

Comment: Please improve your grammar, it is unclear what you are saying, even to an editor

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using `escape` on the client-side, use `encodeURIComponent`. `escape` does **not** do URI-encoding. (It does something similar, but different enough that you'll have trouble.) `encodeURIComponent` does standard URI-encoding. PHP should decode it for you automatically if you're sending the data in the normal way, e.g.:

```
var word = "balaji's";
$.ajax({
    url: "yoururl",
    data: encodeURIComponent("word") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(word)
});
```

If you're not sending the data in the default "multipart form" form (e.g., you're overriding `dataType`), you'll have to decode it yourself via [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: @user: You'll have to post your full ajax call and the PHP code you're using to process it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the PHP functions, [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) or [rawurldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

One difference, it seems, is in the handling of + (plus signs).

You should make sure to test with strings containing plus signs to ensure you have chosen the correct function.

Comment: Neither `urldecode()` nor `rawurldecode()` fully work on data that has been `escape()`d. The general consenus is to use `encodeURIComponent()` instead.

Comment: I downvoted because this can *seem* to work for a long time, until a character is encountered where the functions don't match. Nothing personal @jedwards

Comment: @Pekka, I think it's presumptuous to ask the OP to change the way it's encoded.  The question wasn't "how can I do this from end to end", but rather "how can I decode the strings produced from js's escape()".  Also, I'm not aware of any characters that are encoded by escape() that are not decoded by urldecode(), are you?

Comment: If used on UTF-8 characters outside normal ASCII, `escape()` generates strings like this:  `%u0710` which `urldecode()` can't decode. Changing the encoding method really is the right thing to do here

Comment: Ah, UTF-8 -- one of those things that is so easily forgotten until it breaks your code -- thanks!

Answer (score -2):

as a last resort you can try something like this (this list is not exhaustive, make your own or complete it)

```
$search = ["%20",'%3C','%3E','%3D','%22','%3A','%3B','%E0','%E9','%E8','%26','%E2', '%u2019'];
$replace = [' ', '<', '>', '=','"',':',';','à','é','è','&','â', '\''];

str_replace($search, $replace, $your_str);
```

Comment: No! Why would you do that yourself when PHP has built-in url decoding support.